# Visual Studio Android SeekBar Rotation attribute generates IntelliSense error

Tags: c#, xamarin, layout

In a layout.xml file:

android:rotation="270" for specifically a SeekBar in this case gets the "270" red squiggled with the suggestion that there should be "a unit such as px supplied".
Obviously adding any unit at all generates a complier error.

Is there a place to modify the IntelliSense ruleset to change this syntax check?

Comment: Is it helpful for you ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in Visual Studio and its new Analyzers. Other than the annoyance of it showing up in the error list it shouldn't affect the app build or running it.

If you really don't want to see it give an error，you could go to

**Tools** - **Options** - **Text Editor** - **Android XML** - **Advanced** and uncheck **Enable layout diagnostics** in **Analysis**

Backside of this approach is that IntelliSense does not check your code spelling at all.